# How the server determines which client sent the message in TCP socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

We are using linux TCP sockets in our project. Server is waiting for the connection request using accept() call and once the connection request from client comes, server creates a thread and the thread handles further communication with client. Can any one please let me know if there is any way that server can determine the client (Process id) which sent message.

If any message comes from drivers, our server is broadcasting that message to all clients. In one of the bugs in the field, UI is hanging and UI team is complaining that they didn't receive the message. But we saw the logs and we are broadcasting to all the clients attached. So just we want to prove to which process ids, we are sending the messages.

Comment: Why? What good will knowing the client's process ID do you?

Comment: You can only do that if both client and parent are running on the same host and there is no use to use a server and client in the same host'

Comment: @Anjaneyulu Not correct. Process IDs of clients are unique if they are all running in the same host, but it doesn't have to be the same host as the server. However the process ID is of no use whatsoever *except* as a unique identifier.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu: *"..no use to use a server and client in the same host.."* - really? There are actually lots of uses for client and server on the same host, like connection to the local database, `http://localhost`, ...

Comment: @Anjaneyulu we are running on same machine. Can you please let me know if you are aware of any such method.

Comment: As being on one host, and having source IP-address and -port you could *try* to identify the clients' PIDs by digging around in the local `/proc` file system. But still this would introduce a race as not being an atomic action, so you either find no PID, or the PID you found had already been reused by another process the moment you log it. This approach does not make any sense. Better make the server and clients logs use a sufficient time resolution and compare server and client logs for debugging this.

Comment: "*So just we want to prove to which process ids, we are sending the messages.*" You do not send messages to PIDs. This is a conceptually wrong view of what IP provides. The client could very well pass on the connected socket to an arbitrary number of processes (same for the accepted socket on the server side, BTW). An IP-connection is *not* bound to any PID, not by the server, nor by the client.

Comment: How do you perform a broadcast using TCP connections? Are you talking about sending a message to each client separately? That is not broadcasting.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes. We are storing list of connections and we are sending message to all the connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you just have client's ip address and their source port. In most cases this isn't enough information for client identification. If all of your clients besides in LAN or generally their IP addresses are distinguishable (they have unique public/private addresses) you can use client's ip address, but in case of NAT'ed clients, their ip addresses will be same.
Note that even you have client's ip address, it can be used for distinguishing clients from each other, it doesn't report client process id or any dynamic things related to clients.

You have to implement a protocol which all clients send their identity informations to server, so the server will know about them. The process id or anything related to clients could be sent via your protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The client may be on a remote machine, since you are using TCP, so I am not sure how it would be possible to know the "process id".

What you *can* find out however, is the client's IP and TCP PORT number:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/accept.html

> Either a null pointer, or a pointer to a sockaddr structure where the
>   address of the connecting socket will be returned.

Comment: We are running on same machine.

Comment: OK, but TCP is designed to handle both local and remote connections. What you can do is as e.jahandar suggested implement a protocol to send the `pid` upon connection. Or if you are using Windows and don't care about portability use Named Pipes and `GetNamedPipeClientProcessId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the PID of the client every time it sends a message to the server so that you can identify the one which has sent a message .i.e add PID of client to the message at a fixed location either at the end or beginning and decode the same in the server code .
My sincere advise in this case is to use the select API in the Linux environment so that it monitors all the file descriptors .Here you can identify the client based on the unique file descriptor. Hence might solve your problem
Have a look [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Module41.html)